# Colab GPU execution becomes very slow after certain number of epochs

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I am running an image reconstruction code using neural networks on google colab. I am training the model for 500 epochs using GPU accelerator, but the first 446 epochs are taking 12 sec per epoch to run, the 447th epoch is taking 864 sec and 448th epoch is showing ETA more than 2 hours. The runtime is still GPU, can someone explain why the time taken is increasing so much?
(To note, in one run of the training, the session crashed at the 447th epoch saying it used up all the RAM).

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any code so i can only imagine what the problem might be:

Maybe the model history is growing with each epoch and gets to the point it sucks all the RAM.

I don't know if not saving the output of model.fit solves the problem (i don't even know if you are doing it).

One thing that you can do to patch this problem is to save the model with the function `save_model`, and then restart the session and start the training from a loaded model instead that from zero.

source:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize